# Actual360 convention in quantlib schedule

Tags: programming, bond, quantlib, daycounting, convention

I'm trying to make a payment schedule for different bonds in quantlib. For example, I made such a schedule:

```
schedule = ql.Schedule(effective_date, maturity_date, ql.Period(ql.Semiannual),
ql.India(), ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.Actual365Fixed.Standard, ql.DateGeneration.Backward, False)
```

However, when I am trying to make another schedule with actual/360 day convention, I can't find any method in the class ql.Actual360 (like Standard in ql.Actual365Fixed) that works. I just tried this code:

```
schedule = ql.Schedule(effective_date, maturity_date, ql.Period(ql.Quarterly),
ql.India(), ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.Actual360(), ql.DateGeneration.Backward, False)
```

with just ql.Actual360() instead. I received the following error:

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Schedule'.
```

Is there a way to build a schedule with the Actual360 convention in `quantlib`?

Answer (score 1):

The day-count convention doesn't enter in the schedule construction, which gives you a set of coupon dates.  It only matters after the schedule is built, and gives you a measure of the time between any two dates in the schedule.

You can have the same schedule, but you can calculate the time between its dates according to different day-count conventions.

The fact that the day count seems to be used in the first constructor is misleading.  `ql.Actual365Fixed.Standard` is a Python proxy for an enumeration, and it's actually the number 0.  At that place, the `Schedule` constructor expects a business-day convention, another enumeration, and your 0 is interpreted as `ql.Following`.  You're not using act/365 at all, I'm afraid.